# I'm trying to grep folders and make a variable of the result for further need

Tags: linux, bash

```
GET_DIR=$ (find ${FIND_ROOT} -type -d 2>/dev/null | grep -Eiv ${EX_PATTERN| grep -Eio ${FIND_PATTERN})
```

but somehow when I try to print the result, its empty.
But when I am using my grep without a script I got results on the Command line.

Comment: Drop the space: `$ (` → `$(`

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the pipe `|` and `grep` by using `name` or `iname` (case insensitive) within `find`, for example:

```
find /tmp -type d -iname "*foo*"
```

This will find directories `-type d` that match the pattern `*foo*` ignoring case `-iname` in `/tmp`

To save the output in a variable you could use:

```
FOO=$(find /tmp -type d -iname "*foo*")
```

From the `find` man:

```
 -name pattern
         True if the last component of the pathname being examined matches pattern.  Special shell pattern matching
         characters (``['', ``]'', ``*'', and ``?'') may be used as part of pattern.  These characters may be matched
         explicitly by escaping them with a backslash (``\'').
```

Answer (score 0):

consider using xargs :

GET_DIR=$ (find ${FIND_ROOT} -type -d 2>/dev/null | xargs grep -Eiv ${EX_PATTERN| grep -Eio ${FIND_PATTERN})